# Sending emails using CDO while looping through a DB record set of emails

Tags: loops, asp-classic, recordset, cdo.message

I have a classic ASP recordset that pulls, loops and send emails using CDONTS. The problem that I'm having is that as the recordset iterates through the code users receive their own individual emails and everyone's else emails.

I have not tried fixing this issue however I'm wondering if maybe there is a way to Pause the loop while iterating through in order to ensure each email is sent out at a time.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5;url=young_eagles_volunteers.asp?YEEventID=<% REQUEST("YEEventID") %>">
<title>Young Eagles Confirm Participation</title>
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body class="body">
<%
sendUrl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing"
smtpUrl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver"



Set objConfig=CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
objConfig.Fields.Item(sendUrl)=2
objConfig.Fields.Item(smtpUrl)="relay-hosting.secureserver.net"
objConfig.Fields.Update



Set objMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set objMail.Configuration=objConfig
objMail.From="ye@eaa309.club"
objMail.ReplyTo=""

DIM conn, sql, str_YEEventID
str_YEEventID = REQUEST("YEEventID")


  SET conn = SERVER.CREATEOBJECT("ADODB.Connection")
  conn.OPEN eaa309
  set rsYEReminder=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")

     sql=("EXEC [dbo].[sp_select] @yeEventID = "&str_YEEventID&"")
   rsYEReminder.Open sql,conn



IF NOT rsYEReminder.EOF AND NOT rsYEReminder.BOF THEN

  DO WHILE NOT rsYEReminder.EOF

  HTML = HTML & "<HTML>"
  HTML = HTML & "<HEAD>"
  HTML = HTML & "<TITLE>Reminder</TITLE>"
  HTML = HTML & "<link href='/main.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />"
  HTML = HTML & "</HEAD>"
  HTML = HTML & "<BODY>"
  HTML = HTML & "<img alt='EAA' src='images/YEPart_Reminder.png' border='0'><br><br>"
  HTML = HTML & "<span class='bodysmall'><b>ATTENTION:</b> Volunteer("& rsYEReminder("Full Name") &" - "& rsYEReminder("YEE_VOLUNTEER_TYPE") & ") Please respond by clicking either the Yes or No buttons below if you are still planning on participating in the upcoming Young Eagles Event at "& rsYEReminder("YE_Event_Location_Name") & "</span><br><br>"

  HTML = HTML & "<a href=''><img alt='EAA' src='images/yes_button.png' border='0'></a><br><br>"& vbCrlf
  HTML = HTML & "<a href=''><img alt='EAA' src='images/no_button.png' border='0'></a><br><br>"& vbCrlf

 IF rsYEReminder("YP Status") = "Expired" THEN
 HTML = HTML & "<span class='note'>NOTE: It appears that your Youth Protection Certification has expired. Prior to the event please log into your EAA account by clicking on this link: <a href='accountlogin' target='_blank'></a> Then click My Account and then Training Information - Go to training. When you have completed your training please send an email to the current YE coordinator or chapter secretary. Thank you!</span><br><br>"
 ELSEIF rsYEReminder("Status") = "Not Taken" THEN
 HTML = HTML & "<span class='note'>NOTE: It appears that you've not taken the EAA Youth Protection Certification training course. Prior to the event please log into your EAA account by clicking on this link: <a href='accountlogin' target='_blank'></a> Then click My Account and then Training Information - Go to training. When you have completed your training please send an email to the current YE coordinator or chapter secretary. Thank you!</span><br><br>"
 END IF


  HTML = HTML & "<hr>"
  HTML = HTML & "</BODY>"
  HTML = HTML & "</HTML>"


  objMail.To=rsYEReminder("Email")
 objMail.Bcc="kbnetguy@gmail.com"
  objMail.Subject="EAA CHapter Young Eagle Reminder"
  objMail.HTMLBody=HTML
  objMail.Send

  rsYEReminder.MOVENEXT
  LOOP
END IF



%>

</body>
</html>
```

Only one individual custom email should go out to each person. No users should receive more than one email intended for other users based on the recordset.

Comment: The emails are queued up until they are sent. CDONTS does't know what's in the queue, so there's no way to pause.

Comment: You need to initialize the HTML variable to a blank string at the beginning of the loop.  `HTML = "" `

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the objMail object between iterations. I think each time the loop does objMail.To, you just add the next emailaddress to the mail and send it again.

try moving these lines into the loop:

```
Set objMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set objMail.Configuration=objConfig
objMail.From="ye@eaa309.club"
objMail.ReplyTo=""
```

and then as the last line in the loop write:

```
set objMail=nothing
```